# Strings Immutability

Tags: java, string, immutability

I was told that strings in java can not be changed.What about the following code?

```
name="name";
name=name.replace('a', 'i');
```

Does not it changes `name` string?
Also, where is the implementation of the replace(); compareTo(); equals(); provided?
I am just using these functions here, but where actually are they implemented?

Comment: Note that 1) variables *are not objects* and; 2) the `String.replace` method returns a *new String object* -- the original object is unchanged.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

String.replace() returns a new String.

"name" is a reference to a String object, so it can be reassigned to point to name.replace(), but it will be pointing to a new object.

Here is the [javadoc for String](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), where you can find out what all the methods do.

Comment: what happens to the original object that name was referencing to?

Comment: If "name" was the only reference to that object, then that object is gone and will be garbage collected. If something else is holding a reference to that object, then it will stick around.

Comment: No, it's not immediately GC'd but likely stored in the String pool for a while in case it is needed again.

Comment: Yes. I didn't say when it would be garbage collected.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic case of confusing a reference variable (name) with a String object it refers to ("name"). They are two very different beasts.  The String never changes (ignoring reflection type kludges), but a reference variable can refer to as many different Strings as needed.  You will notice that if you just called

```
name.replace('a', 'i');
```

nothing happens. You only can see a change if you have your name variable assigned to a different String, the one returned by the `replace` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see it for your self:

```
String name = "name";
String r    = name.replace( 'a', 'i' );
System.out.println( name );// not changed 
System.out.println( r    ); // new, different string
```

If you assign the new ref to r, the original object wont change.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't actually demonstrate immutability.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is 

`name="name";
name.replace('a', 'i'); //assignment to String variable name is neglected
System.out.print(name)`

output:

`name`

this is because the `name.replace('a','i')` would have put the replaced string, `nime` in the string pool but the reference is not pointed to String variable name.

Whenever u try to modify a string object,
java checks, is the resultant string is available in the string pool
if available the reference of the available string is pointed to the string variable
else new string object is created in the string pool and the reference of the created object is pointed to the string variable.